# Number of steps to reduce a number in binary representation to 1

Tags: c++

Given the binary representation of an integer as a string s, return the number of steps to reduce it to 1 under the following rules:

If the current number is even, you have to divide it by 2.

If the current number is odd, you have to add 1 to it.

It is guaranteed that you can always reach one for all test cases.

Step 1) 13 is odd, add 1 and obtain 14.

Step 2) 14 is even, divide by 2 and obtain 7.

Step 3) 7 is odd, add 1 and obtain 8.

Step 4) 8 is even, divide by 2 and obtain 4.

Step 5) 4 is even, divide by 2 and obtain 2.

Step 6) 2 is even, divide by 2 and obtain 1.

**My input** = 1111011110000011100000110001011011110010111001010111110001

**Expected output** = 85

**My  output** = 81

For the above input, the output is supposed  to be 85. But my output shows 81. For other test cases it
seems to be giving the right answer. I have been trying all possible debugs, but I am stuck.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <vector>
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
  string s = 
     "1111011110000011100000110001011011110010111001010111110001";
  long int count = 0, size;
  unsigned long long int dec = 0;
  size = s.size();
  // cout << s[size - 1] << endl;
  for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
  {
   // cout << pow(2, size - i - 1) << endl;
    if (s[i] == '0')
        continue;
    // cout<<int(s[i])-48<<endl;
    dec += (int(s[i]) - 48) * pow(2, size - 1 - i);
  }
  // cout << dec << endl;
  //  dec = 278675673186014705;

  while (dec != 1)
  {

    if (dec % 2 == 0)
        dec /= 2;
    else
        dec += 1;
    count += 1;
  }

  cout << count;
  return 0;
```

}

Comment: You should keep the number as string. Division by 2 just means chopping of a trailing `'0'`. Adding 1 to the string is more complex but just a loop toggling `'1'` and `'0'` and maybe adding a final `'1'` to the front.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow I think the exercise is looking for that sort of solution. Trailing 0 is 1 operation each. Then you've found a block of 1s. Adding 1 toggles that block and pops a 1 out the top and so on. There's a solution in there that counts blocks of 1 and 0 dealing with boundary changes.

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/TG1EqEM9G

Comment: @Persixty You can probably do it without all the adding and just count the blocks of 0s and 1s. Would be a far smarter algorithm. You just have to figure out the formula.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow Yes! That's what I mean by a solution that counts blocks. You keep track of what you would have toggled without toggling them. Easy case "1110000" is 4 divide by 2. An add 1. Then 3 more divide by 2, leaving 1. End.

Comment: @Persixty Looks like `s.length() + 1 + <number of 1 blocks>`, right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This line:

```
pow(2, size - 1 - i)
```

Can face precision errors as [`pow` takes and returns `double`s](https://cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/pow/).

Luckily, for powers base 2 that won't overflow `unsigned long long`s, we can simply use bit shift (which is equivalent to `pow(2, x)`).

Replace that line with:

```
1LL<<(size - 1 - i)
```

So that it should look like this:

```
dec += (int(s[i]) - 48) * 1ULL<<(size - 1 - i);
```

And we will get the correct output of `85`.

Note: as mentioned by @RSahu, you can remove `(int(s[i]) - 48)`, as the case where `int(s[i]) == '0'` is already caught in an above if statement. Simply change the line to:

```
dec += 1ULL<<(size - 1 - i);
```

Comment: `(int(s[i]) - 48) *` is unnecessary. It is expected to be only `1`. No?

Comment: @RSahu `s[i]` could be `'0'`. As shown in the example given by OP.

Comment: That is already take care of with the `if (s[i] == '0') continue;` check.

Comment: @RSahu Right. OK. I'll edit it to my answer (since it didn't cause problems, I didn't consider it).

Comment: @Eljay It doesn't affect the answer. But sure, I'll change it.

Comment: Also, if you run through the string from left to right, you don't need to calculate that multiplier. `unsigned long long dec = 0; for (int idx = 0; idx < str.size(); ++idx) { dec *= 2; if (str[idx] == '1') ++dec; }`. If you like compact code, that adjustment can be written `dec += dec + (str[idx] == '1');`. <g>

Comment: @PeteBecker If you really liked compact code, you could do `dec = bitset<64>(str).to_ulong();`.

Answer (score 1):

The core problem has already been pointed out in [answer by @Ryan Zhang](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73390797/434551).

I want to offer some suggestions to improve your code and make it easier to debug.

1. The `main` function has two parts -- first part coverts a string to number and the second part computes the number of steps to get the number to 1. I suggest creating two helper functions. That will allow you to debug each piece separately.

   ```
   int main()
   {
       string s = "1111011110000011100000110001011011110010111001010111110001";
       unsigned long long int dec = stringToNumber(s);
       cout << "Number: " << dec << endl;
       //  dec = 278675673186014705;

        int count = getStepsTo1(dec);
       cout << "Steps to 1: " << count << endl;
       return 0;
   }
   ```
2. Iterate over the string from right to left using `std::string::reverse_iterator`. That will obviate the need for `size` and use of `size - i - 1`. You can just use `i`.

   ```
   unsigned long long stringToNumber(string const& s)
   {
       size_t i = 0;
       unsigned long long num = 0;
       for (auto it = s.rbegin(); it != s.rend(); ++it, ++i )
       {
           if (*it != '0')
           {
               num += 1ULL << i;
           }
       }

       return num;
   }
   ```

Here's the other helper function.

```
int getStepsTo1(unsigned long long num)
{
    long int count = 0;
    while (num != 1 )
    {
        if (num % 2 == 0)
            num /= 2;
        else
            num += 1;
        count += 1;
    }
    return count;
}
```

Working demo: https://ideone.com/yerRfK.